# How to use function as argument in function?

Tags: r

I'm wondering how to add a function to a function as an argument.

There are a lot of functions that can take functions as arguments, such as do.call() and summarise(), just to name a few.

In order to make my functions more generic, I have found this problem to be an occurrence.

```
test_func <- function(x = "value", 
                      f = "function"){
    x %>% f
}
```

The desired result is on out of the two examples below.

```
test_func(x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
          f = mean())
```

or

```
test_func(x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
          f = "mean")
```

Which ought to equate to:

```
c(1,2,3,4,5) %>% mean()
```

Comment: The code with `f = "mean"` works for me. Is that not returning 3 for you?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Adam, unfortunatly it does not work for me, I get the following error message.

    Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "f"

If you know why it works for you and not me, I would love learn more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
findMean <- function(x, FUN = mean, ...){
  mean_of_x <- x%>% FUN(...)
  print(mean_of_x)
}
```